# MapKit/Location Manager crashes app when unloading view

Tags: crash, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I has a bug where my application crashed "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when I hit the back key on my navigation bar and the view unloaded that had a MapKit (mapView) and used the Location Manager.  Tried for days to fix the bug and finally came up with a fix for anyone that comes across this problem:

Add this code to your dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc {
    mapView.delegate = nil;
    locationManager.delegate = nil;

    [mapView release];
    [locationManager release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man! The weird thing is that you can't reproduce it in the simulator.

Comment: Please provide more implementation details. It looks like some obj. is already released. Btw, it's good habit to nil the delegate in dealloc.

Comment: Without seeing crash logs can't really tell. But looks like you are releasing something twice. try adding NSZombieEnabled, this will tell you if you are trying to access something in memory that has already been released.

Answer (score 0):

I had this one too,  :) And, yes, this fix is actually a proper fix;

```
- (void)dealloc {
  mapView.delegate = nil;
  locationManager.delegate = nil;

  [mapView release];
  [locationManager release];
}
```

What happens behind the scenes is this:

1. You hit the backkey. This unloads and in consequence releases the controller which holds the mapView. As there has been quite likely only a single reference to the controller it will be dealloc'ed then.
2. The locationManager, however, is quite likely still referenced somewhere in the inner workings of geopositioning.
3. If the locationManager and/or mapView now send out a notification to their respective delegate, they are following an invalid pointer. Which will result in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

Yes: nilling delegates that point to self is always a good idea. I justed wished Apple would add some automagic there.